# Publishing Left and Right video feeds in ROS using a MYNTEYE stereo camera

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I'm new to ROS and OpenCV and am trying to figure things out. It seems to do anything with vision the camera needs to be calibrated. I found what looks to be a simple method of calibration in the ROS tutorials here: https://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration

However one of the tutorial's assumptions is "a stereo camera publishing left and right images over ROS." I have no idea how to do this. Thanks to anyone that can help me.

This might be a separate issue but when I use the stereo camera in OpenCV it only recognizes it in one index (my built in webcam on my laptop would be 0 and the MYNTEYE would be 1). When it does display it puts both lens views in the same window so it looks like the camera is cross-eyed.

Answer (score 0):

Use MYNT-EYE-ROS-Wrapper for using it

https://github.com/slightech/MYNT-EYE-ROS-Wrapper

Call

```
roslaunch mynteye_ros_wrapper mynt_camera_display.launch
```

to run the wrapper

The modified the published topic from minteye node to feed into stereo calibration node accordingly

Comment: Thank you Dr. Shenghai. I'm getting the following error message when trying to make the Wrapper: CMake Error at MYNT-EYE-ROS-Wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:13 (message):
  MYNTEYE_SDK_ROOT environment variable not found.

Comment: So, after moving moving my environment from my laptop to my desktop your original answer answered my question perfectly. Thanks again Dr. Shenghai.